# How to Turn a Multiple Array Object into Query String Parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, query-string

I have the following object below with multiple arrays.

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "100",
      "name": "PIX"
    },
    {
      "id": "200",
      "name": "Rendimentos"
    }
  ],
  "channels": [
    {
      "id": "300",
      "name": "Chat"
    }
  ]
}
```

The idea is to generate query strings, something like that.

services=100&services=200&channels=300

I know you can do it with map and join, but I would know if it was with a pure object, now this format below, I'm confused

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _"but I would know if it was with a pure object"_. What's stopping you from using `map`, etc?

Comment: Hvae you tried anything yourself ? how is services all of a sudden equal to 100 and 200?

Comment: @SuperDJ it looks like the count of the items in their arrays times by 100.

Comment: @evolutionxbox. I edited the answer with data json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [URLSearchParams() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams).

Iterate your data and append key/value pairs or map an entries array to pass to the constructor

I have no idea what determines the expected output you have shown from the data displayed so am using a simpler data structure for demonstration purposes.

You can combine with `URL()` API to create full url string as shown below also

```js
const data = [
  {name:'foo', value:10},
  {name:'bar', value:20}
]

// Loop and append key/values
const params = new URLSearchParams();
data.forEach(e => params.append(e.name, e.value));
console.log('params:', params.toString());

// Alternate approach passing entries array to constructor
const params2 = new URLSearchParams(data.map(e => [e.name,e.value]));
console.log('params2:',params2.toString())

//Adding to a URL
const url = new URL('http://example.com')
url.search = params

console.log('Full url:',url)
```

Using the updated array data in question:

```js
const data={services:[{id:"100",name:"PIX"},{id:"200",name:"Rendimentos"}],channels:[{id:"300",name:"Chat"}]};

const entries = [];
Object.entries(data).forEach(([k,arr])=> arr.forEach(({id}) => entries.push([k,id])));

const params = new URLSearchParams(entries);

const url = new URL('http://example.com')
url.search = params;

console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're hung up on trying to iterate an object with `map()` or `join()`, which you can't do directly. Instead you can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array and iterate that. Since there is a nested `map()` you can `flat()` it before `join()`

```js
let obj = {
  "services": [{
      "id": "100",
      "name": "PIX"
    },
    {
      "id": "200",
      "name": "Rendimentos"
    }
  ],
  "channels": [{
    "id": "300",
    "name": "Chat"
  }]
}
let queryString = Object.entries(obj).map(s => s[1].map(e => `${s[0]}=${e.id}`)).flat().join('&')
console.log(queryString)
```