# Can't pass an array of objects to a REST endpoint in NET7

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, mapping, .net-7.0

I am trying to pass the following trying to populate an array of objects.

> https://localhost:7101/user/list?Filters={"field"="string","value"="string"}&Filters={"field"="string","value"="string"}

It does not map, the array is empty.

My models look like this:

```
public class UsersQuery
{
  public Filtration[]? Filters { get; set; }
  public Filtration? Donkey { get; set; }
  public string[]? Monkey { get; set; }
}

public class Filtration
{
  public string Field { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried different combination using brackets, curly braces, swagger etc. I manage to populate a field with an object. I manage to populate an array of strings. I can't do both at the same time. How can I investigate it further?

I've followed a few links [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432496/how-to-turn-a-multiple-array-object-into-query-string-parameters-in-javascript), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Comment: You might want to rephrase the URL to decoded version.

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api?rq=2) and check, explaining why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: According to [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40021), the arrays are considered to be part of the body, so you might want to explicitly state that the query object of yours comes in by `[FromQuery]`. Haven't tested it, though, so it might be a poofer.